# Pittorecoli meaning (17th century)

Tags: word-meaning, etymology

In the article *Così Caravaggio uccise un uomo a Milano* ([Il Messaggero, 5 marzo 2017](https://www.pressreader.com/italy/il-messaggero/20170305/281990377312857)) there is the following quote by Riccardo Gandolfi:

> [La biografia di Caravaggio di Gaspare Celio] Racconta che Orsi chiamò tanti "pittorecoli a lodarne l'opera"; e che vedendo quelle figure al naturale e quegli scuri, molti si stupirono.

Is it conceivable that the word pittorecoli meant small painter in the 17th century? I've seen it quoted from a 17th century source but can't find that word anywhere else. Or it's perhaps a contraction?

The French journalist quoting this article in the *Journal des arts* writes "pittorecoli [petits peintres]".

Comment: Can you provide a full quote? That would help a lot.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure of the spelling? *Pittore*, as you'll know, is “painter”. It is conceivable to form *pittorucolo* by using the suffix *[-ucolo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ucolo)* to denote a painter of small value, and *pittorucoli* would be the plural form.

Comment: Pittore Coli may refer to Giovanni Coli (1636-1681) an Italian painter. It’s just an attempt to decode your word...

Comment: I now see quite a number of _pittorucoli_, @DaG. As in "Pittori, pittorucoli, pittorelli erano ingaggiati per le decorazioni...". What's the nuance between those terms?

Comment: Could you add this to your post? I think it's important.

Comment: The link says “We couldn’t find the page you’re looking for. The link might be broken, or the page might have been removed.”

Comment: It works for me when I click it: http://www.pressreader.com/italy/il-messaggero/20170305/281990377312857

Comment: @egreg: It also works for me.

Comment: I get the same answer as @egreg.

Comment: In case it helps the title of the Messaggero article is "Così Caravaggio uccise un uomo anche a Milano", March 5, 2017.

Comment: @egreg: Doing the search ***"Così Caravaggio uccise un uomo anche a Milano" pittorecoli*** with Google,  can you find the article?

Comment: @Charo No, always the same answer. I think the some contents in the site are blocked according to the country the query comes from.

Comment: @egreg That is almost certainly true: if I use a proxy to pretend to be connecting from Italy I get your response, while if I connect directly I can see the article. I'll insert a more complete quote in the OP.

Comment: I cannot find the referenced article on the site of “Il Messaggero”. My feeling is that this is just a typo for *pittorucoli*.

Comment: I can confirm @DenisNardin's experiment, the other way around (connecting from Italy I can't access, but pretending being elsewhere I do).

Comment: @Charo, thanks for contextualizing my post but Gandolfi is actually quoting the text I was mentioning (I have an image of the article; punctuation is lost in the Internet version). I've restored the quotes.

Comment: In fact, it's @DenisNardin who has done it. I've only corrected one word.

Answer (score 3):

It can be simply a typo for *pittorucoli* or maybe how the word was spelled in Celio's biography, which was after all written much before Italian spelling was standardized. In Italian the suffix *-ucolo* can be attached to any noun with diminutive or derogatory effect:

> **-ùcolo** [maybe from lat. *-ūcŭlus*; the popular outcome, very rare, is *-ucchio*]. – Noun altering suffix with diminutive or derogatory value (*chiesucola*, *paesucolo*, *straducola*).
>
> (*From the [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ucolo/)*)

In this context *pittorucoli* probably means something alike to *small-time painters*, painters that are not particularly famous.

@JeanB adds: I don't think it's a typo. In *Catalogo delle pitture che si conservano nelle chiese di Pesaro*, Giovanni Andrea Lazzarini, Pesaro, 1783, I [read](https://books.google.com/books?id=mIZYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=%22pittorecolo%22&source=bl&ots=mJcW_br6Hq&sig=lfLywqa7C1orRMF8P8Tf7eRLDes&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP-_vft-vXAhWJYd8KHWdTCGUQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22pittorecolo%22&f=false) "fece venire all'improvviso da Fano un pittorecolo, ..."

Comment: At this [entry of the Vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pittore/) you can specifically find "pittorùcolo" as "spregiativo" of "pittore".

Comment: Thanks to all. I don't think it's a typo, however. By now, I've found _pittorecolo_ in a number of 18th century texts.

Comment: @JeanB: It would be useful if you add those examples of *pittorecolo*, if you are sure that they are correct, to Denis's answer, or post an answer of your own.

Comment: I've added a _pittorecolo_ reference to the answer. To my ear it sounds better than _pittorùcolo_ and I'm going to use it as a 17th century italianism in the text I'm writing.

Comment: @JeanB It might sound better to *your* ears, but certainly not to mine, and I doubt to those of any other native speaker. That said, it's not too unlikely that the suffix *-ecolo* was indeed productive in the 18th century, as it is not today.

Comment: @JeanB: I agree with Denis: as a native Italian speaker, *pittorecolo* sounds quite awkward. This is not to say that it has never been deliberately used, but be warned that an Italian speaker reading that might assume that it is a misspelling. (Compare this with the relative abundance of instances of *scrittorucolo* and *attorucolo* and the absence of the corresponding form in *-ecolo*.)